# Cordova, onResume() only works when I include alert()

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, push-notification, push

I'm using cordova's push plugin. When the user taps the notification, it takes them to an 'ad page', as expected. But strangely, it only works if I include an alert() in onResume() or if I open the app again after tapping the notification.

```
function onNotificationAPN(e) {
    // Event callback that gets called when your device receives a
    // notification

    imgURL = e.imgURL; //should get set at same time notification appears

    if (e.alert) {
        navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
    }
}

function onResume() {

    alert(imgURL); //1st

    if(imgURL)
    {
        alert(imgURL); //2nd
        window.location.href = "ad.html";
        imgURL = null;
    }
}
```

The first alert shows 'undefined'. But the second alert shows the imageURL set in my notification payload. If I comment the first alert out, the second alert does not appear. But then if I close and reopen the app, it does.

What's going on here?

Comment: ```onResume``` is called before ```onNotificationAPN```. Why don't you do the redirection on ```onNotificationAPN```?

Comment: @jcesarmobile Isn't onNotificationAPN() is called first? It makes the notification appear when the app is running in the background, so I thought it would set imgURL at this time, too.

Comment: put a log on both and see which one is called before, but if imgURL is null unless you use a timeout, ```onResume``` it's probably being called before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you defined imgURL as global variable as it is being used in different functions?  I am not 100% sure, but you can use timeout instead of alert.

```
    var imgURL;

function onNotificationAPN(e) {
    // Event callback that gets called when your device receives a
 // notification

    imgURL = e.imgURL; //should get set at same time notification appears

    if (e.alert) {
        navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
    }
}

function onResume() {

    //alert(imgURL); //1st

setTimeout(function(){ 
        if(imgURL)
        {
            //alert(imgURL); //2nd
            window.location.href = "ad.html";
        imgURL = null;
        }
}, 3000);


}
```

Comment: Ah, yes I have defined imgURL at the top of the js file outside of all functions. Ooo, good suggestion. I forgot about setTimeout. Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: Yep, that appears to also work! Now I just have to figure out why. Thank you!

Comment: @Ethan Fischer: I don't know the reason why this works, but sometimes it helps to insert a timeout of 0 milliseconds.